# make rule for files in subdirectory with the working directory set to this subdirectory

Tags: makefile

I have some source files in a subdirectory:

```
$ ls subdir
foo.x bar.x other_file
```

Now I want to create a rule like

```
subdir/%.y: subdir/%.x
        cmd $< -a option -o $@
```

just that `cmd` needs the working directory set to `subdir`.

I want something that if `subdir/bar.y` is required it is generated like

```
cd subdir && cmd bar.x -a option -o bar.y
```

Is there for example a way to say `$<` and `$@` but without the leading `subdir/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using GNU make, you can use `$(notdir $<)` and `$(notdir $@)` to get the filenames without a directory.  And you can use `$(dir $@)` to get the directory part:

```
subdir/%.y: subdir/%.x
        cd $(dir $@) && cmd $(notdir $<) -a option -o $(notdir $@)
```

Or hardcode subdir, if you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `F` or `D` suffix for the file and directory part respectively.

```
subdir/%.y: subdir/%.x
    cd $(@D) && cmd $(<F) -a option -o $(@F)
```

See the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-g_t_0024_0028_0040_0040D_0029-959) for details.

Answer (score 0):

What about using $(patsubst) ?

```
subdir/%.y: subdir/%.x
        cd subdir && cmd $(patsubst subdir/%,%,$<) -a option -o $(patsubst subdir/%,%,$@)
```

Or, the equivalent but simpler:

```
subdir/%.y: subdir/%.x
        cd subdir && cmd $(<:subdir/%=%) -a option -o $(@:subdir/%=%)
```